# Moving from IIS6 to IIS7.5 - Custom Handlers

Tags: iis-6, httphandler, iis-7.5

I am moving a site from IIS6 on one server to IIS7.5 on another.
This site was not writen by me, and from what I can tell, they use custom handlers to get around the AJAX limitations of the day.
I copied the code from the old server to the new (pre-compieled) and everything works except the "AJAX" stuff. There are several calls in the code to ashx files. These calls return .js files. On the old server this works great. Does not work on the new server.
In the web.config file I found the following lines:

```
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory,AjaxPro.2"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

For some reason this is not working in IIS7.5
Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this could be down to the configuration of the application pool managed pipeline mode. You can easily confirm this by changing the Managed Pipeline Mode for the application pool the site runs under to Classic. If this works and you want to continue to run in Integrated mode then you will need to add a handlers section to the web.config. This is different from the httpHandlers information you noted above.

The new handlers section should be in the system.webServer section. I'm sorry I do not know the exact setting for the item you note but you will need to include the preCondition="integratedMode" if you wish to run in integrated mode.

Comment: Thank you! You nailed it :) Since this is a separate application within the web site, I can allocate it's own app pool. Any down side to haveing a classic mode pool?

Comment: As I understand it I think running in integrated mode allows the use of some additional modules that previously would have required the use of ISAPI extensions to integrate them. You can get some more information about this [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/244/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis7-integrated-pipeline/)

Comment: I'll do a little testing running classic mode and if nothing comes up, I'll just use that. Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing that since IIS6 and asp.net 2.0 use classic mode anyway, if it worked before, it will continue to work.]

Comment: As you say as if it ran fine in IIS6 there should be no problems with it.